# Change the layout of ring visNetwork graph

Tags: r, visnetwork

I create the ring graph below with visNetwork. I would like to know if I can change its default layout to a series of horizontal nodes, with a large curvy arrow going from the last one back to the front, like this below. The first will be the 1 and the last the 4:

[image]

```
library(visNetwork)
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:4,label=1:4)
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2,3,4), to = c(2,3,4,1))
edges$length<-c(90,90,90,750)
edges$smooth<-c(F,F,F,T)
edges$label<-c("","","","")

coords <- matrix(ncol=2, byrow=T, data=c(
  -9,0,
  -2,0,
  7,0,
  14,0.5
  ))
visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>%


visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout.norm", layoutMatrix = coords) %>%
  visNodes(shape = "square", 
           color = list(background = "lightblue", 
                        border = "darkblue",
                        highlight = "yellow"),
           shadow = list(enabled = TRUE, size = 10)) %>%
  visLayout(randomSeed = 12) # to have always the same network
```

Comment: Try `visHierarchicalLayout(direction = "LR")` it will line up horizontally, but the last line from 4 to 1 is hidden under all edges.

Comment: can you check my edited approach with coords and smooth the last edge?